# After recording unable to play back with successfully Login scenario, Getting blank screens User home page is not displayed

Tags: regex, apache, dynamic, jmeter, correlation

```
lt=LT-162191-CwEBk7uKadYp9Ih6t2hjAmslWSLxEe&
```

Unable to extract value using Regular Expression Extractor.

```
Reference name: lt
Regular Expression: lt=(.+?)&
Template: $1$
Matchno: 1
Default Value: Error
```

For above scenario I applied and reference name I passed with ${lt} from the request.

Please provide your feedback.

Note: HTTP Cookie Manager is added.

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine!
Try to use the debug sampler, just after the extraction to make sure ${lt} receives what is expected. Further more, use the view result in tree listener, to actually see the response.
[image]